# How to set a directory inside public as class variable in laravel

Tags: variables, laravel-5, syntax-error

I have a folder named `source` in my laravel 5.4 application which i use quiet often in my controller code.

For example the statement `public_path() . '/source/'` is used in many places in my code and so I want to define the `public_path() . '/source/'` directory as a controller level variable. This way I will just have to use the variable name in all controller functions that use the directory.

This is what I tried and was surprised to see it fail:

```
class PostController extends Controller
{
    public $source_dir = public_path() . '/source/';
}
```

But on the line where `$source_dir` is defined, the application gives the following error:

> FatalErrorException
>   syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';'

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even I don't know exactly error, but I guess the global attribute class can not recognize the function. You may assign in constructor

```
class PostController extends Controller
{
  public $source_dir;
  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->source_dir = public_path('/source/');
  }
}
```